# xpath is not working in this node

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am working with scrapy with python.

I have this html node

```
<div class="comment-right-box">
    <center>
        <h3>
            Call the Seller
        </h3>
    </center>
    <div class="span1">055 176 1262</div>
</div>
```

I want to get the number inside the `span1`

#### I tried this xpath

> normalize-space(.//div[@class='comment-right-box']/center/h3[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Call the Seller')]/parent/following-sibling::div[@class='span1']/text())

I got empty result.

what am I doing wrong?

#### Please don't suggest going directly to the span1 class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `parent` node. You want the first ancestor:

```
normalize-space(//div[@class='comment-right-box']
                /center/h3[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Call the Seller')]
                /ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::div[@class='span1']/text())
```

Or you could also use `../`

```
normalize-space(//div[@class='comment-right-box']
                /center/h3[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Call the Seller')]
                /../following-sibling::div[@class='span1']/text())
```

Comment: Could you check my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109713/scrapy-spider-sends-spider-close-signal-before-it-closes