# scrapy setting couldn't be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to set the `seen` crawled links from spider. i tried this

```
self.settings.overrides['JOBDIR']= "seen_for_"+self.Category+" "+self.Source+" "+self.Action
```

I got exception which means(but no in exact words) that setting is not exist.

I tried imported it like this:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
```

but i got the same exception

then I tried this:

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings
```

but i got that my spider has not been attached to any crawler and really I don't want to attached any crawler because i am just using spider not crawler

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by set the `seen` crawled links? Do you want to avoid re-crawling some URLs? I'm not sure using the settings is appropriate for that -- maybe you want to use [Spider arguments](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments)?

Comment: @elias I am trying to set the duplicated links . got me please?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a list of URLs you want to avoid scraping before running the spider, is that correct?

Comment: @elias yes . please the duplicated job is very popular in scrapy. is my question is bad and not clear ?

Comment: Your question was a little hard to understand because you asked about a problem with settings, but no biggie. So, one simple solution would be to put all the URLs you want to avoid in a file and give it as an argument to the spider. If you are running the spider standalone, you can use it like `scrapy runspider myspider.py -a myfile=/path/to/file_with_urls.txt`.

Comment: @elias no my friend, there is an already build in feature to avoid duplicated items and it works with me in the past, but i lost the code and now i am recoding it. i finished it but i still just need to import the settings. i hope some other users who know what I am talking about to answer me